# CakePHP - HABTM - sending data from multiple tables to a view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

**Scenario:**

```
3 tables:
restaurants
cuisines
features

2 join tables:
cuisines_restaurants
features_restaurants
```

**Question:**

What is the best way to get data for a single restaurant from my controller to the view which includes not only the restaurant data, but also the cuisines and features that it has.

I have it working with this:

```
$restaurant = $this->Restaurant->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Restaurant.id' => $id)));
$this->set('restaurant', $restaurant);
```

And I'm calling it in the view like this:

```
echo "<span class='label'>Name:</span> " . $restaurant[0]['Restaurant']['name'] . "<br />";
echo "<span class='label'>Cuisine:</span> ";
    $cuisineList = "";
    foreach($restaurant[0]['Cuisine'] as $cuisine) {
        $cuisineList .= $cuisine['name'] . ", ";
    }
    echo substr($cuisineList,0,-2) . "<br />";
```

(and repeat for Features)

But this seems overkill, since in all the Cake tutorials I see, the view method in the controller just has:

```
$this->set('restaurant', $this->Restaurant->read(null, $id));
```

Then they call it like this:

```
echo $restaurant['Restaurant']['name'];
...etc
```

**Again - it IS working - I just want to know if there's a better way - the way I'm currently doing it seems sloppy compared to all the other slick things Cake does for me! :)**

Comment: Do you have the recursion set in your models? If you set recursion up to 2, then you should get a huge dataset back. Take a look at Containable as this will help you pear down the dataset. Off the top of my head, what you are doing should return all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working code uses `Model::find('all')`, but when you want to retrieve just one Restaurant's data, you want to use `Model::find('first')`. I think you'll find if you change the first parameter of your call from `'all'` to `'first'`, you'll get the data you want in the format you want.

---

Somewhat tangentially, there is quite literally no difference between the data returned by the two following calls:

```
$data = $this->Restaurant->find('first', array(
    'conditions'=>array('Restaurant.id'=>$id)
));
```

or

```
$data = $this->Restaurant->read(null,$id);
```

[`Model::read`](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#line-1112) is essentially a wrapper for `Model::find('first')`, though it also sets the model's internal state a bit (setting the `Model::id` and `Model::data` properties before returning data retrieved with `Model::find('first')`).

Comment: Just a note - I had to set $this->Restaurant->recursive = 1;  (but you were exactly right - $this->Restaurant->read worked just fine.  I swear I'd already tried that, but - I guess the confidence of hearing it SHOULD be right forces you to go over your code in more detail - THANKS!